# Можно ли в С++ тело лямда-выражения сделать try блоком?

Tags: c++, исключения, lambda, c++17, лямбда-выражение

Часто что бы избежать утечки ресурсов (например дескрипторов) я делаю так:

```
void SomeFunction () try {
    // Тело функции. 
} catch (...) {
    // Тут идёт попытка высвобождения всех дескрипторов. 
}
```

Можно ли в С++ сделать также с лямда-выражением, не создавая вложенную область видимости?

UPD: По просьбе коментирующих добавляю пример кода.

```
void LinuxSpiCommonResourcesAndMethods::InitializeGpioCs(const char* in_gpio_name) try {
    int16_t result_of_writing{ 0 };
    if (gpio_export_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_export_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_cs_file_descriptor_);
    gpio_export_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ = 0;

    // Экспортируем GPIO.
    gpio_export_file_descriptor_ = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); // Подключаем gpio
    if (gpio_export_file_descriptor_ < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file '/sys/class/gpio/export'");
    result_of_writing = write(gpio_export_file_descriptor_, in_gpio_name, strlen(in_gpio_name));

    // Если GPIO уже экспортирован то пытаемся сделать анекспорт и экспортировать снова.  
    if (result_of_writing < 0) {
        gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ = open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); // Подключаем gpio
        if (gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file '/sys/class/gpio/unexport'");
        result_of_writing = write(gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_, in_gpio_name, strlen(in_gpio_name));
        close(gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_);
        if (result_of_writing < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Error writing to file '/sys/class/gpio/unexport'");
        result_of_writing = write(gpio_export_file_descriptor_, in_gpio_name, strlen(in_gpio_name));
        if (result_of_writing < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Error writing to file '/sys/class/gpio/export'");
    }
    close(gpio_export_file_descriptor_);
    gpio_export_file_descriptor_ = 0;

    // Настраиваем направление GPIO
    std::string file_path("/sys/class/gpio/gpio");
    file_path.append(in_gpio_name);
    file_path.append("/direction");
    gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ = open(file_path.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file '" + file_path + "'");
    result_of_writing = write(gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_, "out", 3);
    if (result_of_writing < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Error writing to file " + file_path);

    close(gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_);
    gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ = 0;

    // Открываем файл взаимодействия с GPIO.
    file_path.clear();
    file_path.append("/sys/class/gpio/gpio");
    file_path.append(in_gpio_name);
    file_path.append("/value");
    gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ = open(file_path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file '" + file_path + "'");
    // Проверяем возможность записи в /value файл и устанавливаем cs в 1. 
    result_of_writing = write(gpio_cs_file_descriptor_, "1", 1);
    if (result_of_writing < 0) throw std::runtime_error("Error writing to file " + file_path);
    cs_on_ = true;
}
catch (std::runtime_error& except) { 
    if (gpio_export_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_export_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_);
    if (gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ > 0) close(gpio_cs_file_descriptor_);
    gpio_export_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_directiont_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    gpio_cs_file_descriptor_ = 0;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: А если исключения не выбрасывается, то все дескрипторы благополучно утекают? А что происходит с дескрипторами, выделенными внутри функции? Все это смахивает на проблему XY. А для освобождения ресурсов лучше будет задействовать RAII.

Comment: Если исключение не выбрасывается то выполнится то что вы напишите в коде. И если вы всё сделали правильно то будет работать так как вы задумали. Я думаю вы понимаете что блок try тут нужен когда внутри функции между захватом ресурса и его высвобождением кто-то бросает. RAII тяжело использовать с POSIX функциями. По крайней мерея я не знаю как сделать это легко, не получая большой оверхэд.

Comment: По крайней мере, основные компиляторы (clang, g++, cl), даже в режиме C++17, выдают ошибку в случае подобного определения лямбды.

Comment: @VTT Это во первых. Во вторых в большинстве таких случаях высвободить ресурсы нужно только тогда, когда что-то идёт не так. RAII же вам оставляет не так много вариантов.

Comment: По-вашему выходит, что код для высвобождения ресурсов должен дублироваться в теле функции и в блоке catch, да еще и в каждой функции, которая работает с дескрипторами. Заявление по поводу оверхеда тоже не очень понятно, ведь навешивание catch блоков и дублирование кода как раз выглядит как больший оверхед. Ну и было бы хороши приводить какие-то конкретные примеры. Лично я ни никогда не видел примеров с осмысленным использованием оборачивания тела функции в try блок, даже не особо понятно, зачем кому-то мог понадобиться такой синтаксис.

Comment: Ресурсы должны высвобождаться после того как они становятся не нужны, а не только когда что-то идет не так.

Comment: А что, так можно??? Какое интересное извращение. :-O Как и положено хорошему извращению, делает нечто противоположное поставленной задаче. Дескрипторы, объявленные функцией, будут недоступны в блоке catch и для освобождения их понадобится внутренний try (и зачем тогда внешний?). Или же надо писать в строгом соответствии с RAII (не всегда применимо, к сожалению), и тогда опять же try не нужен.

Comment: @freim блин, вы меня расмешили.

Comment: @VTT добавил пример.

Comment: По-моему тут совершенно тривиально можно было бы написать используя RAII обертку для gpio file descriptor. Одна копипаста блоков `if (gpio_export_file_descriptor_ > 0) close` чего стоит. Я так понимаю, что основная сложность возникла из-за необходимости закрывать сразу пачку (глобальных) дескрипторов при выкидывании исключения. Это можно было бы реализовать без единого try блока путем создания локальных переменных оберток дескрипторов, которые в конце функции перемещались бы в соответствующие глобальные переменные.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, все понятно теперь. По сути, вы пишете не на С++, а на С, в который добавлены исключения, причем функции работают с глобальными переменными. Спорный стиль, но в таком контексте ваш метод действительно работает.

Comment: @freim это не спорный стиль, это С++ который вынужден использовать POSIX. Я сам до ужаса не люблю С стайл, но к сожалению бывают моменты когда от него никуда не деться т.к. в С++ нету замены ioctl. Всё что мне остаётся это как можно быстрее завернуть это всё во враперы и подняться выше. И функции там не работают с глобальными переменными, если вы не заметили это, метод класса. А дескрипторы - это его поля (нижнее подчёркивание в конце имени означает что это private член класса по google style guide).

Comment: @VTT так и скажите что вы не знаете как это сделать =)

Comment: @mrFieldy Я же прямо описал, как это сделать...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817048/why-there-is-no-function-try-block-for-lambda

Comment: @Croessmah большое спасибо а помощь.

Comment: @mrFieldy что значит "вынужден использовать POSIX"? Поскольку вы тут работаете только с файлами - достаточно одной-единственной простейшей обертки чтобы наслаждаться всеми радостями RAII

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я не говорил что POSIX дескрипторы нельзя обернуть в RAII, я только говорил, что в этом примере я вынужден работать с POSIX, поэтому С++ код выглядит как С. Почему я тут вынужден с ним работать? Одна из причин, потому что тут я работаю с SPI а большинство оборудования SPI работает в дуплексном режиме. Через стандартные средства работы с файлами вы не сможете полноценно работать с файлами SPI, только конечно если вы не знаете, как можно работать с файлами в дуплексном режиме.

Comment: У вас некоторые другие методы этого класса открывают /sys/class/gpio/export и остальные  и оставляют их открытыми?  Кстати, а почему в catch вы обнуляете `gpio_unexport_file_descriptor_`, а в основной части нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем именно try-блоком? Чем не устраивает такой вариант?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    auto f = [](int i){ try { if (i==0) throw 0; } catch(...){i++;} cout << i << endl; };
    f(-1);
    f(0);
    f(1);
}
```

P.S. Совершенно согласен с большинством комментаторов, что такое применение try-catch - извращение...